# What does "Enable debug mode" in Eclipse settings do?

Tags: eclipse

In the Eclipse settings under General->Error Reporting there is the option "Enable debug mode". But what does it do? When I search for "Eclipse debug mode" I obviously only get results on how to debug programs with Eclipse, not about this option. I guess it creates more detailed log files?

(Or maybe more general: Is there a detailed explanation of every Eclipse option (at least for core and the normal packs from the official download page) somewhere?)

Comment: I don't have this page on my Eclipse so this isn't part of the core Eclipse. What languages / frameworks do you have installed? Apart from a tiny core Eclipse is all plugins so 'without plugins' doesn't mean much.

Comment: I chose the standard java version from the universal installer. In about 12 hours I can give you my complete installation details. (and with "without plugins" I meant "without custom plugins that are in none of the predefined packs, because those can be infinite")

Comment: Interestingly this option is active in the Eclipse version at my workplace where I left 99% of the options as they were. So either it's active by default or my company activated it in the download version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking as one of the committers from the Eclipse Automated Error Reporting Initiative (AERI), this option is there to help us, the developers of AERI, debug the error reporting itself.

Switching the *General > Error Reporting > Enable debug mode* option on causes every error that shows up in the *Error Log* to cause an “An Error Has Occurred” notification – even if the same error has already been reported from this Eclipse instance. Also, AERI explains how it reaches its decision whether to send the report via additional messages in the *Error Log*.

Unless you are contributing code to AERI or need the extra verbosity to send us a detailed bug report, you should leave that option switched **off** (the default).

Answer (score 0):

Related to the tooltip "Disables recently seen filters and increases the logging output" i assume that this is for sending exceptions and other error to the eclipse-developer team directly.

In the same page you can adapt the error reporting configuration.
When you install eclipse you get ask whether you want to support eclipse in sending errors to them. If you do not agree, this preference page helps to get it to work later on.